# Is it a sin to have such a book?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a book on argumentation, and there are practical works to consolidate the material, so it says there: "There is no God, because he did not come to me during prayer" There you need to write what is wrong from the point of view of argumentation. Is it considered a sin that I have such a book? What should I do with it?

Comment: I am a westerner, and only slowly learning about the Quran. As such, I would call this a comic book. You could as well say "There are no craftsmen, because no one came to repair my piping". No offense meant.